# How can I save logged users email in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, api, react-hooks, next.js

I have this login API. i wan't to save logged users email in state or something else. so I can show it on header after the login. user email is in the `data.email` .

login.tsx

```js
    const LoginAuth = async (data: AuthenticationProps) => {
        await axios.post(baseURL + `client/auth/login`,
        {
            email: data.email,
            password: data.password,
        },
        {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                Accept: "application/json",
            }
        }
        )
        .then((res) => {
            if(res.status === 200) {
                router.push("/Home");
            }
        }, (err) => {
            console.log(err);
        })
        
    }
    return {
        LoginAuth,
    }
}
```

Comment: use [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) ?

Comment: few options -->
1. use local or session storage.
2. use a state . and pass that state to a header component.
3. or useContext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways of achieving this:

1. You can simply have a state, that's accessible, but most likely you are using different components:
2. You can employ [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext). This will allow to share the state
3. If you want the email to be persistent between session then you could use localstorage and set a context at app start.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Context API, and wrap your whole React app inside it. That way you can access these details from anywhere in your app.
[Context API doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)